# How to use return Listview.builder in appbar

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have a firabseModelList and i need to get data by index. I can do that in this area:
[image]

Working codes like this:

```
return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: firabseModelList.length,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.8, right: 12),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Container(
                            .....
                            ...
                           Positioned(
                           ...
                           child: Text(
                           firabseModelList[index]
                           .weatherValue.toString() + "°",
                           style: const TextStyle(
                           color: Colors.white,
                           fontSize: 20.0,
```

But how can i use **ListView.builder** and **itemCount: firabseModelList.length**, etc. in appbar? This code is my recent situation:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
.....
....

child: Text(
              firabseModelList[index].weatherValue.toString() + "°",
```

I take index error because i need like this code:

```
return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: firabseModelList.length,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.8, right: 12),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

All codes:

```
class _Kulturel1001 extends State<Kulturel1001> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateDisplayInfo(widget.weatherData);
  }

  int? temperature;
  Icon? weatherDisplayIcon;
  //AssetImage? backgroundImage;

  void updateDisplayInfo(WeatherData weatherData) {
    setState(() {
      temperature = weatherData.currentTemperature!.round();
      WeatherDisplayData weatherDisplayData =
          weatherData.getWeatherDisplayData();
      //backgroundImage = weatherDisplayData.weatherImage;
      weatherDisplayIcon = weatherDisplayData.weatherIcon;
    });
  }

  final Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("2doga")
      .doc("kulturel")
      .collection("1001");
/*  final Query query = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance.collection("content3");*/

  List<FirabaseWeatherModel> firabseModelList = [];

  Future<int> findWeather(GeoPoint geoPoint) async {
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(
        // ignore: unnecessary_brace_in_string_interps
        'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${geoPoint.latitude}&lon=${geoPoint.longitude}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      var currentWeather = jsonDecode(data);

      try {
        var currentTemperature = currentWeather['main']['temp'];
        var currentCondition = currentWeather['weather'][0]['id'];

        var findWeatherData = currentTemperature!.round();

        return Future.value(findWeatherData);
      } catch (e) {
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print(e);
      }
      return 0;
    } else {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('Could not fetch temperature!');

      return 0;
    }
  }

  Future<List<FirabaseWeatherModel>> chnageList(
      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) async {
    firabseModelList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.docs.length; i++) {
      var itemData = snapshot.docs[i].data();
      GeoPoint location = snapshot.docs[i].data()["location"];
      var returnResult = await findWeather(location);
      FirabaseWeatherModel firabaseModel =
          FirabaseWeatherModel(weatherValue: returnResult);
      firabaseModel.itemData = itemData;
      firabseModelList.add(firabaseModel);

      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("olusandata");

      //item.distance = getDdistance;
    }
    return firabseModelList;
  }

  int findWeather1() {
    return 22;
  }
```

I added these codes because i couldn't explain myself properly.
When i use like this, it is works normally:

```
return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: firabseModelList.length,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.8, right: 12),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Container(
                              height: 214.8,
                              width: 188.4,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  right: 16.8, bottom: 50),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.6),
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                      querySnapshot.docs[index].data()['image'],
                                      maxHeight: 200,
                                      maxWidth: 200),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Stack(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () => gotoPage(querySnapshot
                                          .docs[index]
                                          .data()['title'])),
                                  /*  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      CupertinoPageRoute(
                                          builder: (redContext) => MyApp()));*/

                                  Positioned(
                                    bottom: 0.0,
                                    left: 0.0,
                                    right: 0.0,
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.8),
                                      child: BackdropFilter(
                                        filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                                            sigmaY: 19.2, sigmaX: 19.2),
                                        child: Container(
                                          height: 80,
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                height: 5.0,
                                              ),
                                              Align(
                                                child: Container(
                                                  alignment:
                                                      Alignment.topCenter,
                                                  //  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                                  child: IgnorePointer(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      querySnapshot.docs[index]
                                                          .data()['tr'],
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 25,
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                          fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                              .normal),
                                                      //  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              const SizedBox(
                                                height: 5.0,
                                              ),
                                              Row(
                                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment
                                                        .spaceEvenly,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    width: 3.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      decoration:
                                                          const BoxDecoration(
                                                        borderRadius:
                                                            BorderRadius.all(
                                                                Radius.circular(
                                                                    4.0)),
                                                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                                                      ),
                                                      child: getImage(
                                                          querySnapshot
                                                              .docs[index]
                                                              .data()[
                                                                  'zpositioned1']
                                                              .toString(),
                                                          150),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    width: 3.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      child: getImage(
                                                          querySnapshot
                                                              .docs[index]
                                                              .data()[
                                                                  'zpositioned2']
                                                              .toString(),
                                                          150),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    width: 3.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      child: getImage(
                                                          querySnapshot
                                                              .docs[index]
                                                              .data()[
                                                                  'zpositioned3']
                                                              .toString(),
                                                          150),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    width: 3.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      child: getImage(
                                                          querySnapshot
                                                              .docs[index]
                                                              .data()[
                                                                  'zpositioned4']
                                                              .toString(),
                                                          150),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    width: 3.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      child: getImage(
                                                          querySnapshot
                                                              .docs[index]
                                                              .data()[
                                                                  'zpositioned5']
                                                              .toString(),
                                                          150),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    width: 3.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      child: getImage(
                                                          querySnapshot
                                                              .docs[index]
                                                              .data()[
                                                                  'zpositioned6']
                                                              .toString(),
                                                          150),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    width: 3.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      child: getImage(
                                                          querySnapshot
                                                              .docs[index]
                                                              .data()[
                                                                  'zpositioned7']
                                                              .toString(),
                                                          150),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    width: 3.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      child: getImage(
                                                          querySnapshot
                                                              .docs[index]
                                                              .data()[
                                                                  'zpositioned8']
                                                              .toString(),
                                                          150),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    width: 3.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      child: getImage(
                                                          querySnapshot
                                                              .docs[index]
                                                              .data()[
                                                                  'zpositioned9']
                                                              .toString(),
                                                          150),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    width: 3.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  //Expanded(
                                                  //  child: Center(
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      height: 30,
                                                      width: 30,
                                                      alignment:
                                                          Alignment.center,
                                                      decoration:
                                                          const BoxDecoration(
                                                        borderRadius:
                                                            BorderRadius.all(
                                                                Radius.circular(
                                                                    4.0)),
                                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                            29, 172, 188, 1),
                                                      ),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        firabseModelList[index]
                                                                .weatherValue
                                                                .toString() +
                                                            "°",
                                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                          fontSize: 20.0,
```

Comment: please let me know in detail what should you do about this??

Comment: you can also use with  toolbarHeight  property or create preferredSize widget

Comment: I want to use " firabseModelList[index].weatherValue.toString()" in appbar but i can't right now. So i want to help me how can i do that.

Comment: you need to get data in the initState  then you can access this data in appbar action widget or you use provider package to update the values using change notifire

Comment: Can you please show me exactly. I will give you vote for that

Answer (score 0):

I will not fall in how to get data from firebase, but coming straight to your question, you can use your data like this in appbar

```
class _DummyScreenState extends State<DummyScreen> {

  List<String> services = ['ball','joystick','bat'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var ScreenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var ScreenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: ScreenHeight * 0.05,
            width: ScreenWidth * 0.18,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: services.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(

                    child: Text(services[index]),
                  );
                }),
          )],
      ),);
  }}
```

Comment: Can you look at the topic, i added more codes.

Comment: You tried the solution i provided in answer?

Comment: Yes i did but where i get the error is: firabseModelList[index].weatherValue.toString() "index" have an error

Comment: what's the error can you please share?

Comment: Undefined name 'index'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: please check spell is the index you declare in builder are same? If yes please share code of listview builder you tried now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242000/discussion-between-berkan-and-ahmad-raza).

Comment: issue resolved or not?

Comment: Still have issue..